# вывести из базы банных определенные таблицы

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста каким запросом можно вывести из БД mySQL только те таблицы которые содержат в названии ***_db?

Comment: Прописывать в ручную каждый запрос, или использовать JOIN, если имеется реляция между таблицами.
```select * from mytable_db```

Comment: Копайте в сторону `information_schema`

Answer (score 1):

Есть один "костыль". С помощью него можно получить список таблиц, с подходящими под требование именами.

```
$database = "имя_базы_данных";
$sql = "show tables where `Tables_in_".$database."` like '%_db'";
```

После этого можно циклом выудить все необходимые данные, так как список таблиц уже известен.

К сожалению, в текущий момент не могу проверить, будет ли работать данный пример на PHP, но в phpMyAdmin такой запрос корректен и выводит то, что нужно.

[image: Пример запроса]

Answer (score 0):

Решение придумал вот такое, все просто и работает :) Всем спасибо за ответы!!!

```
$result =  mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM u938234302_nxt LIKE '%_db'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++)
{
   echo mysql_tablename($result, $i), "\n";

}
```